# Change wordpress blog limit to months rather than by number of posts

Tags: wordpress, navigation, pagination

Is there a way to override how wordpress displays a number of posts on a listing of posts page, regardless of page type (archive, category, posts, tags etc.)?

I'm transferring content from a static site where the pages are saved using a month format.

I'd like to be able to set wordpress' previous/next link navigation to work using months, rather than the limit of posts per page.

So if the navigation would go forward/backward to the previous/next month where there is published content.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a WordPress Query will work?
Such as... (Not tested)

```
$month = date('m');
$query = new WP_Query( 'monthnum=' . $month );
```

As the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) lists